# C Memory address problem

Tags: c

```
int intarray[256] = {0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
int* ptrA;
ptrA = &intarray[0];
```

if pta is the content of the local variable, which is the address of intarray[0], then what is the pta +5 means?

anyone can explain? thanks

Answer (score 4):

It points to the sixth element. Pointer addition carries an implicit multiplication by the size of the target type.

Comment: sizeof int is not equal to 1... : `pta+5 != &pta[5]`

Comment: No @Phong. As Simon said -- adding to a pointer takes the sizeof() into account.

Comment: @Phong, ptrA is a integer pointer (int *) therefore when you do say `ptrA + 5` it actually means `ptrA + 5 * sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int intarray[] = {0,11,12,13,14,15,...,19};
int* ptrA = intarray;

int v = *(ptrA + 5); // v == 15
```